# run selected code chunks in knitr by filtering names of code chunk

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, rnw

I am implementing an algorithm which has a lot of formulas in knitr. So I define some functions in some code chunks with names in the pattern `<<Fun_bar>>=@`, and define unit test in other code chunks with names in the pattern `<<Test_foo>>=@`. Now, I only want to run the function definition code chunks. Is there any functionality that could only execute those code chunks with names starting with "Test" ?

Answer (score 3):

You can set `eval` to `TRUE` dynamically for chunks with labels that match `Test_` using [option hooks](http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks/#option_hooks), e.g.

```
<<setup, include=FALSE>>=
knitr::opts_hooks$set(eval = function(options) {
  options$eval = grepl('^Test_', options$label)
  options
})
@
```

Comment: Hi, Yihui, thanks for the answer. Do I miss something, I just paste your code into the setup chunk of me and I have a chunk named <<TestPredict,  eval= TRUE>>=, but this chunk is still running when I run "run all" in Rstudio. Or do you mean , this only works when Rstudio knit the pdf?